# Reference architecture for monetizing a web application

Tags: web-applications

Can anyone point me to a reference architecture or use-case model for monetizing a web application (implementing billing, licensing, subscription.....etc)?

I hear about SaaS often, but I'm not sure how that could be utilized.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Amazon Flexible Payments Service](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/) or [Amazon DevPay](http://aws.amazon.com/devpay/).